# Can I use a list of functions, as input, for a different function in Haskell?

Tags: list, function, haskell

I am struggling to figure out how to make a function that takes a list of functions as input to generate some output. For example,
let's say that I make a type synonym called Func10 like so:

```
type Func10 = Int -> Int
```

I can create a set of functions that add, subtract, divide or multiply a value to 10 like so:

```
add10 :: Func10
add10 input = 10 + input

subtract10 :: Func10
subtract10 input = 10 - input

times10 :: Func10
times10 input = 10 * input

divide10 :: Func10
divide10 input = 10 `div` input
```

Now let's say that I want to make a function that will take a list of 4 values and a list of functions that I want to apply to them: add10, subtract10, multiply10 and divide10.

Initially I thought that I could give the function in the list input the integer argument when I need it, like so:

```
test_function :: [Func10] -> [Int] -> Int
test_function function input = function[0] (input[1])

main = do
    print("print 5 add 10")
    print(test_function [add10, subtract10] [3,5,7,9])
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
function_lists2.hs:17:32: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Integer] -> t0 -> Int'
                  with actual type `[Func10]'
    * The function `function' is applied to two arguments,
      but its type `[Func10]' has none
      In the expression: function [0] (input [1])
      In an equation for `test_function':
          test_function function input = function [0] (input [1])
   |
17 | test_function function input = function[0] (input[1])
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

function_lists2.hs:17:45: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Integer] -> t0'
                  with actual type `[Int]'
    * The function `input' is applied to one argument,
      but its type `[Int]' has none
      In the second argument of `function', namely `(input [1])'
      In the expression: function [0] (input [1])
   |
17 | test_function function input = function[0] (input[1])
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^
```

I thought that this could be because test_function needs the integer input as part of calling test_function, like so:

```
test_function :: [Func10] -> Int
test_function function = function[0]

main = do
    print("print 5 add 10")
    print(test_function ([add10, subtract10] 5))
```

However, this resulted in a similar error:

```
function_lists2.hs:26:26: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Integer] -> Int'
                  with actual type `[Func10]'
    * The function `function' is applied to one argument,
      but its type `[Func10]' has none
      In the expression: function [0]
      In an equation for `test_function':
          test_function function = function [0]
   |
26 | test_function function = function[0]
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^

function_lists2.hs:30:30: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Integer -> [Func10]'
                  with actual type `[Func10]'
    * The function `[add10, subtract10]' is applied to one argument,
      but its type `[Func10]' has none
      In the first argument of `test_function', namely
        `([add10, subtract10] 5)'
      In the first argument of `print', namely
        `(test_function ([add10, subtract10] 5))'
   |
30 |         print(test_function ([add10, subtract10] 5))
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What would be the correct way of doing this? I am trying to take a list of functions and apply them to some other values but it's hard to find information on this topic online. Thanks.

Comment: To take an item from a list you need to use `!!`. Your first function would be written like `testfunction function input = (function !! 0) (input !! 1)` but generally manually taking items from lists is a bad idea, you should pattern match or loop through the list

Comment: why are you using list in this way... i never had the need to index a list, so what are you trying to do here...

Comment: Ah yes, @Zpalmtree you're right. I completely forgot that to call an nth index form a list you use !!. That solves the error.

HuStmpHrrr I was trying to create some AI "players" and I needed to use the list of players in a functioni that would calculate the next state of the program.

Comment: What result exactly you want `test_function [add10, subtract10] [3,5,7,9]` to return?

Answer (score 1):

Like Zpalmtree said in the comments, the error was not using !! to call indexes. The correct way to write the code was to have it written out like so:

```
test_function :: [Func10] -> [Int] -> Int
test_function function input = (function !! 0) (input !! 1)

main = do
    print("print 5 add 10")
    print(test_function [add10, subtract10] [3,5,7,9])
```

Comment: or `(function <*> input) !! (0*4 + 1)`.